# Oracle JDBC connection failure

Tags: oracle, jenkins, jdbc, junit

I am experiencing a very strange problem , I have few Junit test cases which create JDBC Oracle connection and close when they are done. For example I have 5 junit

1. FetchTest
2. InsertTest
3. UpdateTest
4. DeleteTest

First 2 test cases are running perfectly fine, But when 3rd test case is try to connect to Oracle through JDBC its through Exception

> Exception occured while creating connection object using DriverManager
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)  at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)   at
>   oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:199)    at
>   oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:211)     at
>   oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:227)
>     at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)   at
>   oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)    at
>   oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:122)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:78)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1179)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:366)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:752)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:359)   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:221)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)

And then my 4th Test will also run fine, getting connection and deleting data as expected.

I also tried to ignore 3rd Test case, And then the 4th test case giving same Exception.

What are the possible cause of this exception ?

Is this any issue with time ? Because this exception occur in daily build in Jenkins

> ```
> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:421)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
> ```

Comment: I don't see any error message. Is that the full exception stack trace? It could be that you don't have enough entropy on your system. If so you can try the following system property -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom

Comment: @JeandeLavarene i have edited the question with exception trace.Please have look and advice me if did something wrong here.

Comment: "_create JDBC Oracle connection and close when they are done_" Can you show how you are dealing with that in a [mcve]? I would bet on a connection leakage here

Comment: @AxelH I am closing connection in every junit as soon as i done with connection so its not seems to connection leak..